# Different font types in postscript text

Tags: fonts, postscript

How is it possible to use different font types in a single text line in postscript?

If the postscript processor displays a single line using the "show" command, how does one use two different font types in the same sentence. For example make some works bold, make some italic, etc.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

PostScript doesn't show 'lines' at all, it just shows text. If your text extends off the page, then it gets chopped off, it doesn't 'wrap around'. Its up to the author of the PostScript program (that's you if you're doing this manually, or the authoring application more generally) to get the layout of text correct. That's what font metric files are for.

Now, when you draw text it is positioned at the current point, so to do what you describe all you do is show the first piece of text, then change fonts and show the second piece of text. The current point is updated after the first piece of text is drawn, so the second chunk is written at that point, ie immediately after the first piece.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ken.